# Supersized image is not styled properly

Tags: jquery, image, supersized

I've made a website with *supersized slider* and caption over every image.
The slider looks fine, but some images are not styled properly at iPad portrait resolution.

- Just 3 slides look like this:
  [image]
- And the other images look weird: 
  [image]

Could someone tell me why only 3 of all images are styled properly?

Comment: What size are the images? are they the same size? what are their aspect ratios?

Comment: All images have 1600  x 700 (width x height). Slide was looking good before insert captions.